# Disable colour output from /etc/init.d scripts?

Tags: redhat, service, init.d, color, capistrano

On RedHat/CentOS systems, all of the service management scripts in /etc/init.d (and also run by the "service" command) produce color output.  (i.e. the "[  OK  ]" and "[FAILED]" strings.)  How do I disable this?  (The color-producing escape sequences are making the webistrano output more ugly than it needs to be.)

Comment: Do you mean [ OK ], [ FAILED ] flags when starting/stopping?

Comment: @quanta Yes; question updated.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `/etc/sysconfig/init`.  The top lines on my CentOS 5.x system:

```
# color => new RH6.0 bootup
# verbose => old-style bootup
# anything else => new style bootup without ANSI colors or positioning
BOOTUP=color
```

Changing the BOOTUP line to something like `nocolor` eliminates the formatting for all init scripts.

If you just want to disable formatting on one of your scripts, add:

```
BOOTUP=nocolor
```

after the line that reads:

```
/etc/init.d/functions
```

Comment: This works even when running scripts manually (i.e. not during bootup), amazingly enough.  Is there any way to do this on a per-script basis, though?  I'd rather not touch `/etc/sysconfig/init`.

Comment: I've expanded my answer above.